# Sample Grabber Filter strange garbage line in the data

Tags: c++, winapi, directshow

I am extracting a raw data of frames from a video file (mov,h264) using Sample Grabber Filter. I use BufferCB callback option to receive the data.

Everything works smoothly for me except that for a couple of files I get a strange line present in the file (which passes almost through diagonal). I tried to debug the data and noticed that at each line there are 2 zeroes in the data which are supposed to be 255 and they change their column position row by row.

Here is the image:

[image]

And here is it's raw data for first 8 x 5 pixels:

[image]

This happens with all the frames in the file. This is just the first frame that is why it is completely white.

The Windows Media Player, however, does not show up this line.

Any ideas what can cause this and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What is the resolution of your image? This maybe due to stride/pitch where the image data is byte aligned for performance reasons, usually 4/8-byte aligned. So if you have say a 8-bit RGB image which is some odd width like 178 pixels then doing the maths shows that 178 * 3 = 534, then if we divide by 4 = 133.5 meaning that the memory will have 0.5 * 4 bytes = 2 bytes of padding.

Comment: Your point hit the target. I checked and the examples that had this issue. Their dimensions are not divisible by 4. And actual data length is equal to  H x W x 3 + 2 x H. So there is a 2 bytes of padding per each line. I am trying to find  a way to do a right data manipulation.

Comment: @EdChum, I am trying to eliminate those additional padding bytes with a clever iteration but I am failing for some reason. I also need to reverse the data since the first bytes of the data correspond to the last row of the image (btw, do you know why the data is reversed). Do you know what is the right way to solve this?

Comment: The data may be reversed because it's bottom up which is how rgb bitmaps can be stored usual they indicate this with negative height or pitch, I'm answering this on a mobile so can't explain further but you should be able to Google these terms

Comment: I think there is a bug in the SampleGrabber filter. Because of those 2 bytes of additional padding I have to have 2xH bytes of additional correct data at the end. Unfortunately, those are completely filled with zeroes. And when I skip 2 bytes after each row I get the image rotated by about 45 degrees + some of the garbage line still exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to be a Sample Grabber bug, and more likely to be either incorrect handling of media type, in part of stride alignment, or ignoring changed media type/stride on the Sample Grabber connection. The visual effect is typical for the class of problems where expected and actual image differ in certain properties.

The first thing to do is to check media type on pin connections when the graph is running. The media type might be different from expected, and also from the media type at the moment of running the graph. Additionally, media type trace will let you calculate the stride and compare to the one in your code.

Note that RGB media types have typically image strides aligned to 32-bit boundary. Then sometimes filters prefer to allocate larger buffers, esp. wider than pixel width of the video, esp. for performance reasons, and pad the video on the right. You are supposed to be handling this when you process the data.